# How to implement logging properly without violating solid principals?

Tags: logging, log4net, nlog

I am trying to implement logging via NLog and there are some code smells that are really asking for my attention but currently due to my limited knowledge I am not sure how to handle them.

Here are the things that I don't like

First of I have hidden the actual implementation of NLog behind an Interface to be used along with DI and that class is a singleton.

Currently I am trying to log as much info as possible this means that I am calling the logger from almost every method in my business objects and I don't like the dependency I am creating on the Logging class. Is their any better way to do logging from every method rather than calling the methods directly? Here I believe I am violating Open Closed Principal because if I make change in the logging interface methods. All Hell will break loose and that change will ripple almost in every method.

Secondly the more scary part is that I need to pass some extra information to my logger in some cases like UserID, ProductCode etc. If I pass that info as paramerter to the logger class, I don't even want to think down that road... How do more experienced guys deal with these scenarios?

Kindly give your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really try logging with Aspects.  See http://www.voelter.de/data/articles/aop/aop.html or just google "logging with aspects"

Comment: Thanks Ray your answer lead me in the right direction. I used Post Sharp in my case and must say now my point of view of working with Cross Cutting Concerns has changed altogether! Thanks Mate!

Comment: Yes, cross cutting is a whole new way of thinking.  Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

You could design the built-in logging of your business objects in a generic way where loggers can be attached to the object to receive logging events or not.  That way you can later change the method in which your logs are recorded without altering your business object code.

Something like:

```
public interface BOLogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}

public sealed class AbstractBOLogger : BOLogger
{
    public List<BOLogger> Loggers { get; private set; }

    public AbstractBOLogger
    {
        this.Loggers = new List<BOLogger>();
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        this.Loggers.ForEach(logger => logger.Log(message));
    }
}

public class BusinessObject
{
    public BOLogger { get; private set; }

    public BusinessObject
    {
        this.BOLogger = new AbstractBOLogger();
    }
}
```

Something like this anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is exactly what I am doing right now but this is exactly what I don't want to do. See here you have a dependency on the AbstractBlogger class in the Business object. Suppose you have 500 business object and logging is required in all of them so you would add dependency to the logger everywhere and later if you change something in the logger you'll need to touch the business objects. Thats not SOLID code. I opted for the suggestion that Ray Trask provided. I went with using PostSharp and m now really satisfied with my implementation Thanks 4 ur input :)